# Where is the source code for entity framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I know EF is open source on CodePlex, but I don't see the branch for the currently released 5.0 build.  Where can I get this source code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't any.  They have only open sourced the post 5 builds.  The very first checkin *MIGHT* be close enough, but then again, it might not.